# two different framed box in running head using fancyhdr

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, framed

I would like to get the two different filled framed box in the odd and even side running head. Expected are:
[image]

[image]

my MWE is:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum}
\pagestyle{fancy}    
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter Title here}
\lipsum[1]
\section{A Level Head}
\lipsum[2-3]
\lipsum[4-12]
\end{document}
```

How do get the two different frame box?

Comment: You want those boxes extending to paper width?

Comment: @Harish: I want those boxes extend to text area

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are different ways of doing it (like using `background`, `eso-pic` packages) but you asked `fancyhdr`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE]{\hspace*{-0.2\headwidth}\colorbox{green!20}{\makebox[\dimexpr0.2\headwidth-2\fboxsep][c]{\strut\thepage}}%
               \colorbox{green}{\makebox[\dimexpr\headwidth-2\fboxsep][l]{\strut\rightmark}}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\colorbox{green}{\makebox[\dimexpr\headwidth-2\fboxsep][r]{\strut\rightmark}}%
                \colorbox{green!20}{\makebox[\dimexpr0.2\headwidth-2\fboxsep][c]{\strut\thepage}}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter Title here}
\lipsum[1]
\section{A Level Head}
\lipsum[2-3]
\lipsum[4-12]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How to set `\thepage` should be in marginplace and `chaptermarks` are in end of text position.

Comment: @Balaji Like that?

Comment: If i have increase the `\thepage` fontsize the box is increase only `\thepage`. I want to increase both the boxes are `same width`. How do adjust that.

Comment: @Balaji: With this minimal setup, you  have to do it manually. Add `\vphantom{\Large\thepage}` (assuming that `\thepage` is `\Large`) in the second box.

Answer (score 7):

Not very different from Harish's solution, but more modular.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{16.5pt}% fancyhdr tells you the length
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE]{%
  \small
  \makebox[0pt][r]{\balajipage{1cm}}%
  \balajihead{\quad\nouppercase{\leftmark}\hfill}%
}
\fancyhead[LO]{%
  \small
  \balajihead{\hfill\nouppercase{\rightmark}\quad}%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\balajipage{1cm}}%
}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyfoot[L]{\balajipage{\textwidth}}%
}


\definecolor{balajipage}{rgb}{0.90,0.93,0.53}
\definecolor{balajihead}{rgb}{0.83,0.87,0.10}

\newcommand{\balajipage}[1]{%
  \begingroup\fboxsep=0pt
  \colorbox{balajipage}{\balajistrut
    \makebox[#1][c]{\thepage}%
  }%
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand{\balajihead}[1]{%
  \begingroup\fboxsep=0pt
  \colorbox{balajihead}{\balajistrut
    \makebox[\textwidth][s]{#1}%
  }%
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand{\balajistrut}{%
  \vrule width 0pt 
    height 1.5\ht\strutbox 
    depth 1.5\dp\strutbox
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter Title here}
\lipsum[1]
\section{A Level Head}
\lipsum[2-3]
\lipsum[4-12]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How do increase `box` in outer `margin side` like `\thepage` same size in `outer margin`.

Comment: @Balaji I can't understand what you mean.

Comment: I have updated the image (odd side image - page no. 7). Please check the rule should go on upto `paperwidth`.

Comment: Use a wider length instead of `\balajipage{1cm}`, say `\balajipage{3cm}`

Answer (score 4):

This uses `tcolorbox` boxes and the `\pagemarkwidth` length to change the widths of the boxes.

The `tcolorbox` approach requires more setup, but is quite configurable too...

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}%
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum}
\pagestyle{fancy}    
\usepackage{calc}%
\newlength{\pagemarkwidth}
\setlength{\pagemarkwidth}{20pt}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RE]{%
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=green,arc=0mm,auto outer arc,left=0mm,right=0mm,boxrule=0mm,top=0mm,bottom=0mm,width={\headwidth-\pagemarkwidth}]
\raggedright\rightmark
\end{tcolorbox}
}
\fancyhead[LE]{%
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=yellow,arc=0mm,auto outer arc,left=0mm,right=0mm,boxrule=0mm,top=0mm,bottom=0mm,width={\pagemarkwidth}]
\centering\bfseries\thepage
\end{tcolorbox}
}

\fancyhead[LO]{%
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=green,arc=0mm,auto outer arc,left=0mm,right=0mm,boxrule=0mm,top=0mm,bottom=0mm,width={\headwidth-\pagemarkwidth}]
\raggedleft\leftmark
\end{tcolorbox}
}
\fancyhead[RO]{%
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=yellow,arc=0mm,auto outer arc,left=0mm,right=0mm,boxrule=0mm,top=0mm,bottom=0mm,width={\pagemarkwidth}]
\centering\bfseries\thepage
\end{tcolorbox}
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter Title here}
\lipsum[1]
\section{A Level Head}
\lipsum[2-3]
\lipsum[4-12]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, since the OP changed the question to something not prevalent in the original version (page numbers at the marginpar), my solution does not answer the question in this range. This is annoying :-(