# image messing up footer

Tags: pdftex, header-footer

I have a footer spanning across the full page. I found a similar question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/213545/two-different-framed-box-in-running-head-using-fancyhdr).
Insted of page number I want a logo. Now inserting an image messes up the footer.

Expected

[image]

What I am getting

[image]

the current used code is

```
\fancyfoot[RE,RO]{%
              \hspace*{-0.2\headwidth}\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\colorbox{gray}{\makebox[\dimexpr0.2\headwidth-2\fboxsep][c]{\includegraphics[width=0.05\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{./ORGLogoShort}}}%
              \colorbox{gray}{\makebox[\dimexpr0.98\headwidth-2\fboxsep][l]{\strut ORG Group}}%
              \colorbox{gray}{\makebox[\dimexpr0.22\headwidth-2\fboxsep][l]{\strut \thepage}}}
```

How can I align the logo with the rest of the footer?

Comment: You are (again) using `\strut`s in some parts of your footer and not in others. My suggestion would be to set the footer in a single box and raise `ORG Group` and `\thepage` into position.

Answer (score 1):

The [graphbox package](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/graphbox/graphbox.pdf) "is an an extension for the LaTeX2e package graphicx to facilitate the placement of graphics relative to the current position using additional optional arguments `[...]` of `\includegraphics`."

Among others it provides the option `align=c` to control the vertical alignment (see page 5 of the documentation).